# NSCompoundPredicate is giving unexpected results

Tags: swift

I must admit I am quite new to predicates. I have a form that the user fills out and based on this information, it should search through the saved data and return a relevant result. The code for this is:

```
let numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayersPicked
    let minTimeForPredicate = minTime
    let maxTimeForPredicate = maxTime
    let gameTime = "averageplaytime"
    let minPlayers = "minplayers"
    let maxPlayers = "maxplayers"
    let minPlayersPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K <= %D", minPlayers, numberOfPlayers)
    let maxPlayersPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %D", maxPlayers, numberOfPlayers)
    let minTimePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %D", gameTime, minTimeForPredicate)
    let maxTimePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K <= %D", gameTime, maxTimeForPredicate)
    let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [minPlayersPredicate, maxPlayersPredicate, minTimePredicate, maxTimePredicate])
```

numberOfPlayersPicked, minTime and maxTime are from the previous screen. An example of when I feel it is returning wrong information is when numberOfPlayersPicked = 1, minTime = 120 and maxTime = 999 (the time is set by a segmented control). The data retrieved has minplayers = 1, maxplayers = 2 and averageplaytime = 60. I'm not sure why it is retrieving this, clearly I am misunderstanding something entirely!

Edit: I've tried to print a load of results to see if I can spot anything that happens.

```
print(andPredicate)
print(numberOfPlayers)
print(minTimeForPredicate)
print(maxTimeForPredicate)
print(games[0])

minplayers <= 1 AND maxplayers >= 1 AND averageplaytime >= 0 AND averageplaytime <= 30
1
0
30
<NSManagedObject: 0x6100000a5640> (entity: GameInCollection; id: 0xd0000000003c0000 <x-coredata://31C3474F-7C40-4C47-AF2D-883A76F922C6/GameInCollection/p15> ; data: {
averageplaytime = 150;
barcode = "";
gametitle = "1 5 150";
maxplayers = 5;
minplayers = 1;
})
```

[print statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZrb2.png)

[print results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0pzW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing these attributes as strings rather than integers?
It could be that you're doing a comparison on the string values rather than their true numerical value, which would produce these kinds of unexpected results.

Comment: Yes this was it! I changed my Core Data saving to be storing Integers instead and all seems to be working now.